# Map vector onto plane and get angle between it and other plane intersection

Tags: math, vector, geometry

I'm making a game using the Unity3D game engine and C#.

In my game I have two 3d vectors, A-B and C-D. I'd like to determine the angle E but I dont know enough geometry and math to work out how.
[image]

What I want to do is..
Project the vector C-D onto a plane thats normal to A-B .
Then measure the angle on the plane between this projected vector and another vector that represents the intersection between the plane and another plane which has a completely flat orientation.

In your answer I'd appreciate it if you wrote the equations as if they were code (ie. this variable multiplied by this one divided by this etc.) and not mathematical notation which I dont know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we decompose `cd` in a part that is parallel to `ab` and an orthogonal part. By subtracting the parallel part, we get the remaining orthogonal part which is equivalent to the projection on the desired plane:

```
cdProj = cd - dot(ab, cd)/dot(ab, ab) * ab
```

The desired angle is then simply given by the arcsine:

```
e = asin(cdProj.y / length(cdProj))
```